# Difference between $0 and $SHELL

Tags: shell

I would like to know the exact difference between $0 and $SHELL. I know that these two are used to know the shell info. 
It would be great if some one explain with examples.

What does it indicate if both show different values as below ?

```
# echo $0
ksh
# echo $SHELL
/sbin/sh
#
```

Comment: Note that shell variables (and just about everything else) are case sensitive in unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SHELL` is just an environment variable, while `$0` is the path of the currently running program.  The user should set `SHELL` to the value of the preferred shell, similar to the way the user sets `PAGER` and `EDITOR`.  Any program that needs to spawn a shell should check the value of `SHELL` to determine which shell to invoke.  `SHELL` is *not* the path of the shell you get when you login.  It will not change when a new shell is run any more than `PAGER` will change if it is set to `less` but the user invokes `more`, or if `EDITOR` is set to `vi` and the user runs `emacs`.  For instance:

```
$ echo $0 $SHELL
bash /bin/bash
$ exec csh
% echo $0 $SHELL
csh /bin/bash
```

Comment: It making some sense. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

$SHELL gives the full path to your **default** shell.

$0 gives the name of your **current** shell.

Comment: Thanks  for your quick reply. But how come these two variables are pointing to two different shells. That is, $0 is indicating it is a Bourne shell while $SHELL is contradicting by saying it is a korn shell ? Could you please throw some light here?

Comment: @Vinod: how are you running ksh? Is it your login shell?

Comment: Your login shell is sh and the shell you're executing the commands from is ksh. It looks like you are running a graphical environment and opened a ksh prompt from there, are you?

Comment: @Wooble, I am not sure from where it is getting set. As soon as I log in, I am getting these two values. I am not explicitly running any shell. I guess this has to do some thing my .profile setting.

Comment: @Before I am not running any graphical environment as such.