# How to prevent R system command syntax error

Tags: r, syntax-error, system

I am trying to run a command similar to

```
> system("cat <(echo $PATH)")
```

which fails when run from within R or Rstudio with the following error message:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(echo $PATH)'
```

However, if I run this on the command line it works fine:

```
$ cat <(echo $PATH)
[...]/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

I checked that the shell I am using is bash using `system("echo $SHELL")`. Can anyone help me solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax works in bash but not sh. The `$SHELL` environment variable doesn't necessarily mean that is the shell being used. `echo $0` will show your shell.

```
system("echo $0")
#> sh
```

You could force bash to be used like this

```
system("bash -c 'cat <(echo $PATH)'")
#> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the crystal clear explanation (this works for me)! I was unaware of the difference between `$0` and `$SHELL`; for reference for others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804517/difference-between-0-and-shell) is a good explanation.